# Uploaded medium blob truncated on download

Tags: php, mysql

I upload a blob to my sql database table with a field that is defined to be of size *medium blob*.  The blob is actually a pdf file of size 4.3mb.  The file is uploaded via ftp.  After upload, some php code inserts it into the database.  I've checked the file within the ftp folder and I can view it correctly.  I've checked the file (blob) within the database and I can view it correctly.  Both sizes show 4.3mb.  If I try to download the file using some code provided by another programmer (below), the file is truncated at about 300kb.

```
if (!($dbLink = mysql_pconnect($db_server,$db_id,$db_pwd)))
{
    print("Failed to connect to database!<BR>\n");
    exit();
}
if(!mysql_select_db($db_name,$dbLink))
{
    print("Cannot use the database!<BR>\n");
    exit();
}

$query = "SELECT name, type, content FROM table_name WHERE link_id = '" . $id . "'";

$result = mysql_query($query, $dbLink) or die('Error, query failed');
list($name, $type, $content) = mysql_fetch_array($result);

//header("Content-length: $size");
header("Content-type: $type");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$name");
echo $content;
exit;
```

I checked my maximum packet size within MySQL and it appears to be about 256mb.  My php.ini shows 10mb for posts.  I'm at a loss as to why the file is truncated.  Can someone please point me in the right direction to solve this?

Comment: it is almost always better to not use blob, and store files, in the file system

Comment: try to provide content-length, like `header("Content-length: ".strlen($content));`

Comment: @Dagon Roger that.  But, I don't have the luxury of doing that right now.

Comment: Not your problem, but worth mentioning: `MEDIUMBLOB` has a maximum size of 16 MB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this with a different methodology.  No matter what I tried from several different examples, I could not get the suggested PHP code to stop truncating files.  I stopped storing the file as an attachment in the database, and, simply stored it in a separate folder on the server.  The database was updated to insert a "path" link for the file.  I changed the php code to:

```
// Construct an HTTP header that will force the browser to display/download the file.
      header("Location: ".$location); 
      ob_flush();
      exit;
```

This forced a relocation to the actual file stored on the server.  The file now opens in the browser.  Note: I also had to change some html code to force the file to open in a new tab in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

The PDO interface between PHP and MySQL offers a streaming scheme for LOB-handling. Seeing as how the mysql_ interface was abandoned years ago by its developers, it might be worth trying this.

See this: http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.lobs.php

You might consider using code like this.

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:dbname=testdb;host=127.0.0.1', 'username', 'password');

$query = "SELECT name, 
                 type, 
                 OCTET_LENGTH(content) AS length, 
                 content 
            FROM table_name 
           WHERE link_id = :link_id
           LIMIT 1";

$stmt = $db->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute(array(":link_id" => $id));

$stmt->bindColumn(1, $name);
$stmt->bindColumn(2, $type);
$stmt->bindColumn(3, $length);
$stmt->bindColumn(4, $data, PDO::PARAM_LOB);  /* binds as a stream */

if ($stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOUND)) {

    header("Content-Type: $type");
    header("Content-Length: $length");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$name");
    fpassthru($data);
}
```

Sorry to say I haven't debugged this. But it's a fairly common use case.

Comment: Ollie...thanks for the info.  This looks promising.  I'll try to implement this in the code and report back.

Comment: Ok...I've tried the code you proposed.  I added some debug echo statements to take a look behind the scenes and it would appear that the length it is grabbing from the table is correct.  However, it still truncates.  Could it be a problem with the way it is served up to the browser, or, the fact that when the file is inserted, I call "addslashes" on the content?  I read another post that offered that as a possible problem.